# NSStream with SSL - Cocoa Echo Server/Client - CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9800)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ssl, nsstream

I'm trying to configure and iOS device to connect to a macOS device over a WiFi network using Bonjour and NSStreams. I'd like to secure the connection via SSL. I started from Apple's Cocoa Echo example code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CocoaEcho/Introduction/Intro.html). It works beautifully without SSL, but when I try to configure a secure connection, I'm getting `CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9800)` on both the client and server side. Here's my configuration.

**macOS (server)**

```
// establish connection
CFReadStreamRef readStream = NULL;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = NULL;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault, nativeSocketHandle, &readStream, &writeStream);
if (readStream && writeStream) {
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
    CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);

    SQConnection * connection = [[SQConnection alloc] initWithInputStream:(__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream outputStream:(__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream];
    [self.connections addObject:connection];
    [connection open];
    [(NSNotificationCenter *)[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(SQConnectionDidCloseNotification:) name:SQConnectionDidCloseNotification object:connection];
    NSLog(@"Added connection.");

}

// open streams (in SQConnection.open)
[self.inputStream  setDelegate:self];
[self.outputStream setDelegate:self];

// SSL
[self.inputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
[self.outputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];

NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @(FALSE), kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain,
                          kCFNull, kCFStreamSSLPeerName,
                          nil];
CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)self.inputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)settings);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty((CFWriteStreamRef)self.outputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)settings);

[self.inputStream  scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.inputStream  open];
[self.outputStream open];
```

**iOS (client)**

```
NSInputStream * istream;
NSOutputStream * ostream;

if ([netService qNetworkAdditions_getInputStream:&istream outputStream:&ostream]) {
    NSLog(@"OPEN STREAMS");
    self.inputStream = istream;
    self.outputStream = ostream;
    [self.inputStream  setDelegate:self];
    [self.outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [self.inputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
    [self.outputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
    [self.inputStream  scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.inputStream  open];
    [self.outputStream open];
}
```

My best guess is that I haven't actually configured a certificate to be used for SSL negotiation. This is something I was hoping macOS would take care of automatically, but Apple's docs are woefully incomplete on this. The best I've found is [a couple paragraphs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html) on "Securing and Configuring the Connection."

Comment: did you have any luck with this?